# Easy way to attach a piece of info to my Vaadin widgets?

Tags: java, vaadin

Is there any way to attach a piece of information, an object reference, to my individual widgets in a Vaadin app?

Seems like this might be handy way to help tell my widgets what to do at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `setData` & `getData`

Yes. Every widget in Vaadin inherits from the [`AbstractComponent`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.html) class. On that class is the handy pair of [`setData`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.html#setData(java.lang.Object)) and [`getData`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.html#getData()) methods.

You can pass any object to that method, with the object reference held by that widget. This facility is strictly for your own use as the app developer, for your convenience. Vaadin and the widget make no use of the object.

You can even store multiple objects by passing a [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) to `setData`.

### Do Not Confuse "Data" & "Value" Commands

Do not confuse these `getData`/`setData` commands with [`getValue`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#getValue())/[`setValue`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#setValue(T,%20boolean)). The "Value" commands are indeed used by the widgets to access their content being displayed in the user interface.